# Cannot run VBA Because of Syntax Error (when recording) & Object-Defined Eerror (when running)

Tags: vba, excel, macros, syntax-error

I am getting the same error as Dennis did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500538/cannot-run-visual-basic-editor-because-of-a-syntax-error-whilst-recording-macro), but the answer that he provided simply said to remove some modules or rename them. However, I only have one module, and renaming it did nothing for me. I even tried making a whole new workbook and copying the macro over to that for a fresh start, but it also did nothing. ***When I go to run the macro after it was recorded, it also gives me an "application-defined or object-defined" error.*** The formula works by itself completely fine outside of the macro, but I do need it as a part of the macro.

Here is what excel recorded, and this is the line in my macro that is giving me the error:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=2,RC[-14],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=4,CONCATENATE(RC[-14],"":"",RC[-12]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=6,CONCATENATE(RC[-14],"":"",RC[-12],"" - "",RC[-10]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=8,CONCATENATE(RC[-14],"":"",RC[-12],"":"",RC[-10],"" - "",RC[-8]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=10,CONCATENATE(RC[-14],"":"",RC[-12],"":"",RC[-10],"":"",RC[-8],"" - """ & _
    ","""")))))"
```

It has a `Range("Q3").Select` prior to that, which activates that cell. Furthermore, if you look at what it recorded vs. the original formula, you can see it leaves off the `K3)` or `RC[-6]),`. I tried to add it, but it did not help.

Original Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=2,C3,IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=4,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=6,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3," - ",G3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=8,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3,":",G3," - ",I3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=10,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3,":",G3,":",I3," - ",K3),"")))))
```

I also tried the formula without the `concatenate`, but it did not help either. It is below:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=2,RC[-14],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=4,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=6,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"" - ""&RC[-10],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=8,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"" - ""&RC[-8]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=10,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"":""&RC[-8]&"" - ""&RC[-6],"""")))))"
```

Edit: Here is the code directly above, and the P3 formula works fine:

```
 Range("P3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(RC[-14]:RC[-1],1,IF(COUNT(RC[-14]:RC[-1])=1,COUNT(RC[-14]:RC[-1]),COUNT(RC[-14]:RC[-1])*2-1))"
    Range("P3").Select
    Range("P3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("P3:P" & LastRow)


    Range("Q3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=2,RC[-14],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=4,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=6,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"" - ""&RC[-10],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=8,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"" - ""&RC[-8]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=10,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"":""&RC[-8]&"" - ""&RC[-6],"""")))))"
    Range("Q3").Select
    Range("Q3").AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q3:Q" & LastRow)
```

I am using Microsoft Office 2013, and there is an ASAP Utilites add-on, which has never caused me a problem before, if that helps at all.

Comment: Random guess but don't use `activecell`.

Comment: I have no idea what to use otherwise to insert a formulas. I have always just recorded it, and it always uses that.

Comment: Don't record. Or edit the recording ~_^ Instead of `activecell`, do `workbook.worksheet.range`. Edit: object defined error means the object is bad. In this case, the object is `activecell` so you want to specify it.

Comment: @findwindow Didn't work. Also, I have a formula I paste in just prior to this and it uses `activecell` and it works fine.

Comment: Uh, don't copy it verbatim, replace it with _your_ book/sheet/range.

Comment: @findwindow I didn't copy it verbatim. When I did that it did not work. It shouldn't even need to specify the workbook or sheet regardless. the `range()` should default to the active worksheet, am I wrong?

Comment: @findwindow I posted the formula that inserts before it runs into this error.

Comment: Well, if P3 works, Q3 should as well so uh I don't know. I still suggest replacing activecell as best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the formula itself contains an error:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=2,RC[-14],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=4,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=6,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"" - ""&RC[-10],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=8,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"" - ""&RC[-8]),IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=10,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"":""&RC[-8]&"" - ""&RC[-6],"""")))))"
```

should be

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=2,RC[-14],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=4,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=6,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"" - ""&RC[-10],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=8,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"" - ""&RC[-8],IF(COUNTA(RC[-15]:RC[-2])=10,RC[-14]&"":""&RC[-12]&"":""&RC[-10]&"":""&RC[-8]&"" - ""&RC[-6],"""")))))"
```

at the `...RC[-8]),IF...` there shouldn't be a `)`!

If you delete it, the macro runs without fail.
Still: I suggest changing your formula

```
=IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=2,C3,IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=4,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=6,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3," - ",G3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=8,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3,":",G3," - ",I3),IF(COUNTA(B3:O3)=10,CONCATENATE(C3,":",E3,":",G3,":",I3," - ",K3),"")))))
```

to

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTA(B3:O3)/2,C3,C3&":"&E3,C3&":"&E3&" - "&G3,C3&":"&E3&":"&G3&" - "&I3,C3&":"&E3&":"&G3&":"&I3&" - "&K3),"")
```

which is shorter ;)

For the part of "false" recording: If excel "translates" your formula to R1C1, and the string is cut into multiple rows, then sometimes parts are missing. For that case (if you notice the formula is cut to multiple rows) simply select the cell and run in immediate window: `?ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` to get the formula in R1C1. But do not forget to double up all `"`.

Comment: Pesky little `)`... Thanks Dirk!