# Cannot Run Visual Basic Editor Because of a Syntax error on Application.Calculate

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a VBA Excel model which I have separated into two separate workbooks:
`InputsWB`, which contains all the inputs for the model, and
`RunnerWB`, which contains the bulk of the VBA code (and all the class modules live here).
Depending on the needs of the user, the `InputsWB` can either call the macro in the `RunnerWB` or the `RunnerWB` can call multiple versions of the `InputsWB`. The detail doesn't matter for this question but the two workbooks need to be separated.

Mysteriously, after the split I sometimes get a `Run-time 1004 error` with the message `Cannot Run Visual Basic Editor Because of a Syntax error`. If I `Debug + F5` then the code runs until it encounters the next `Application.Calculate`.

I have seen many similar questions [while recording macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20500538/cannot-run-visual-basic-editor-because-of-a-syntax-error-whilst-recording-macro), or on [`Application.Calculate`](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/736873-application-calculate-causing-runtime-error.html). I think mine is related to the `Application.Calculate`, but those answers don't explain why this happens. Some reasons I can think off, but cannot confirm online is:

1. There are Modules in the two workbooks with the same names (although I've changed the modules names in the `InputsWB` but still get the error on occasion.
2. There are VBA functions in the two workbooks with the same names

Are there any other reasons why I could be getting these errors?

## UPDATE (2019/12/02)

I finally realised why I got this error. I am calling a macro in my `RunnerWB` from my `InputsWB`. However, there was a duplicate function declared in my RunnerWB. Usually, this would give a `Compile error: ambigious name detected` when the macro was initiated from ThisWorkbook. However, because it was initiated from another workbook I got the `Syntax error` explained above.

## UPDATE (2020/07/22)

I am now getting this error again on `Application.Calculate` right at the end of the run. Which breaks me is that I use `Application.Calculate` many times during the run.

## UPDATE (2020/07/23)

I found the issue that caused the bug at last.

- I had a sub called `Main` in a Module called `Main`
- One of the buttons in my workbook referred to this button, and because the names are the same it links it as `Main!Main`
- Later I renamed the module to `MainSub`. The button still worked, but something inside VBA was broken which was triggered in some `Application.Calculate` executions.

## Conclusion

Never give your sub the same name as your module in VBA, as this may cause problems down the line.

Comment: Is there a reason you dont just use an XLAM add-in?

Comment: I don't need to use the VBA functions in Excels it's just used by the macro in the background @braX. The model will also be used by many different users (some may have firewalls which doesn't allow add-ins to their Excel).

Comment: Then why not just name functions differently?

Comment: I can't think that that would be causing the issue given they are in separate VBA projects. My project is also at 5000 lines of code, so wouldn't want to make major changes to the code and functions unless I know why that is causing an issue.

Comment: I'd start by exporting and re-importing all of the code modules (or use http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/CodeCleaner.htm) to make sure there's no "gunk" in your projects.

Comment: @TimWilliams I deleted all my modules as suggested in the `InputsWB` and then error was gone. I now just added the functions and modules I need instead of having duplicates. So I can confirm neither of the above possible reasons in my question were plausible. So it remains a mystery why this happens (like all the other people who have asked similar questions).

Comment: I've never seen this error so I can't offer any other suggestions here.  Does your existing code write or remove code from the VBA project at runtime (via VBE extensibility functions) ?

Comment: @TimWilliams no it doesn't. I did notice that I had the same macro in both workbooks that had the same shortcut assigned to them. Not sure if that could cause problems.